# Cloure compiler error, couple weeks ago there was no error

Tags: google-closure-compiler

JSC_PARSE_ERROR: Parse error. ')' expected at line 305 character 18 in flow.js
        async(ec, this);

```
 async(function () {
      this.fire('complete');
    }, this);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue, please follow https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/issues/2336 for updates.